# Android Error duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzai$zza.class

Tags: android

I am currently having some trouble running my project.

> **duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzai$zza.class**

The error is saying that I have a duplicate dependency, but I can't see a duplicate anywhere!

The error appears on this line of code:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'`

It says that it has found versions 9.8 and 8.4. I only see version 8.4 though.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tedrasoft.templategoogle"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode=7
        versionName="1.6"
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "ed282ffa-1e9e-4dd8-9edc-cfdcbe8376bd",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "3902815545"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile files('libs/chartboost.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
        compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
        compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.1.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.1.0.jar')

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make these versions match... so `8.4.0`, not `+` which pulls the latest `9.8` I think, now?

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
```

Also, these are 1) unneccessary lines (because of `compile fileTree`), and 2) you should [make them like the others](http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=jackson) and not use jar files.

```
compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.1.0.jar')
```

Comment: Changed to 8.4 and now I have this error.                                         Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.

Comment: I never said that `8.4` would exist, I just said the versions needed to match

Comment: Ah I see, fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it's because of the

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
```

I change it to this:

```
 compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'){
        exclude group:"com.google.android.gms"
    }
```

No more problem!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade google play services (maps, location and gcm) from 9.0.0 to 9.2.0

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
```

Then add this dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
```